# Embedded ASCII control characters getting stripped from string

Tags: c#

I am embedding ASCII control characters in a string, and for some reason, they are getting stripped out.

Example:

```
"a\x03b"[1]
// 59 ';'
"a\x03b".Length
// 2
```

On the other hand:

```
"a\x03mb"[1]
// 3 ''
"a\x03mb".Length
// 4
("a" + '\x03' + "b")[1]
// 3 ''
("a" + '\x03' + "b").Length
// 3
```

Comment: `\x03b` is a single char... `3*16+11=59`

Comment: @L.B, yep... figured that out.  I thought others might run into the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
"a\x03b"
```

is this string:

```
 "ax"
   ^
   +- the single character with the unicode code point \x03b
```

this, on the other hand:

```
"a\x03mb"
```

is this string:

```
"axmb"
  ^
  +- the single character with the unicode code point \x03
```

When you embed an escaped unicode code point in the string, ensure that the following characters can not be understood to be a part of the hexadecimal value specifying which character to encode.

```
\x03b   <-- b is a valid hexadecimal character
\x03mb  <-- m is not, however, so the escaped character is just \x03
```

The [documentation for specifying character literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) has this to say:

[image: hexadecimal-escape-sequence]

meaning that the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th hexadecimal digits are *optional*. However, the compiler is unable to understand that this `"\x03b"` is supposed to be two characters, `'\x03'` and `'b'`, and you didn't really mean that `"\x03b"` is the single character `'\0x3b'`.

Basically, if the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th character are hexadecimal characters (0-9, A-F), then they are assumed to be part of the escaped code point.

Is there a way to ensure you really mean `'\x03'` followed by `'b'`? Sure, just tuck on enough zero-digits in front of the escaped code point to give it 4 hexadecimal characters:

```
       +- the letter b
       |
"\x0003b"
 ^-+--^
   |
   +-- the single unicode code point \x0003 (or \x3, \x03, \x003)
```

Comment: <rant> In my opinion, the C# compiler team should've **required** 4-digit escaped unicode code points in string and character literals to avoid this kind of problem. It will only add a few bytes to the source code as the compiled string will be the same bytes as it was anyway. </rant>

Answer (score 1):

According to the C# spec for [hex-literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), all characters after the first are optional.  Therefore, the trailing `b` is being interpreted as part of the hexadecimal literal.

```
  \x03 == \x0003
 \x003 == \x0003
\x0003 == \x0003

 \x03b == \x003b
```

Since `m` is not a valid hex character, it does not get parsed as such.

Specify the full 4 character literal to avoid the problem.

```
"a\x0003b".Length == 3
```